# Eliminar la primera linea de un array y almacenar resultado (php)

Tags: php

Busco la manera correcta  de abrir un archivo de texto cargar el contenido a un

> array

Eliminar la primera linea y guardar nuevamente el contenido en el mismo archivo de texto.

sin la linea eliminada uso este ejemplo:

```
<?php
$ra= file("datos.txt");
$s = unset($ra[0]);

$file = fopen("datos.txt", "w");
fwrite($file,$s);
fclose($file);
?>
```

El problema es que el resultado es un archivo de texto sin contenido.

Espero alguna idea.

Comment: si quieres elimimar el primer elemento de un array con php es `array_shift($arreglo);`

Comment: Gracias por el dato pero aun no logro almacenar el resultado en el mismo documento

Comment: quieres leer todo un archivo, eliminar luego la primera linea y finalmente guardar el cambio?

Comment: Exactamente como notas logro cargar el archivo de texto en la variable **$ra** trato de eliminar la primera linea usando **unset($ra[1]);**  y finalmente trato de guardar  el resultado usando ***fopen();** pero no funciona

Comment: la prueba lo estas haciendo en un servidor? o en tu maquina local, esta pregunta es por si tienes errores de permisos, trata de cambiar el file por `fopen("datos.txt" , "r")`;, probablemente cuando haces file el archivo esta abierto , verifica que nada abra este archivo solo tu programa y si aun no sabes que error esta dando colocalo en un try/catch

Comment: No seria unset[0]? para la primera linea?

Comment: Las pruebas las realizo en un servidor  y en la maquina local y creo que buscare otra forma gracias

Comment: Lo que no logro es devolver el valor a **$ra** con las lineas sobrantes  **$ra** no tiene valor luego de pasar por  **unset($ra[0]);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo: Espero te sirva. Saludos

```
<?php

// Inicializamos nuestras variables
$i=0; //contador de línea que se está leyendo
$numlinea = 0; //línea que se desea borrar a esa se le asigna el indice, iniciando en 0 como primera 
$aux = array();

// Abrimos el archivo
$archivo = fopen('datos.txt','r');
if($archivo){
// Hacemos un ciclo y vamos recogiendo linea por linea del archivo.
    while ($linea = fgets($archivo))
    {

  if ($i != $numlinea)  // Si la linea que deseamos eliminar no es esta 
  {
    $aux[] = $linea; // La agregamos a nuestra variable auxiliar
}

  // Incrementamos nuestro contador de lineas
$i++;
}

// Cerramos el archivo.
fclose($archivo);

// Convertimos el arreglo(array) en una cadena de texto (string) para guardarlo.
$aux = implode($aux, '');

// Reemplazamos el contenido del archivo con la cadena de texto (sin la linea eliminada)
file_put_contents('datos.txt', $aux);
echo "Se elimino la linea '$numlinea'";
}else{
    echo "Ocurrio un error al abrir el archivo";
}
?>;
```

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo funciona bastante bien

Comment: Hola amigo tengo una pregunta a cual variable se le asigna el valor a elimina te pregunto por que me gustaría ocupar la variable antes de eliminarla

Comment: $numlinea = 0; //línea que se desea borrar, a esa se le asigna el indice, iniciando en 0 como primera posicion

Comment: te entiendo pero esa variable solo tiene el valor 0 y lo que me interesa es el valor de la primera linea del archivo de texto

Comment: Encontré esta solución abrir  **$ra= file("datos.txt");**  y asignarle el valor a** $s **de esta manera ** $s = $ra[0]; ** y luego ejecutar tu código

Comment: Bueno, al menos te sirvio.